# Effiently incorporatinig metadata (.xml) into rastered landcover data (.tiff/.toff.ovr/.tiff.vat.dbf)

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, land-cover, nlcd

I'm using [this VGIN data](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=d3d51bb5431a4d26a313f586c7c2c848) to understand land cover surrounding points in Virginia in QGIS. The VGIN data came with ~100 tiles (and for each there is a .tif, .tif.ovr, and .tif.vat.dbf file) and two .xml files, one of which contains the land use classifications at specific values, along with other metadata.

I am 100% self-taught on QGIS and pretty much GIS entirely.

Is there a way to be using these files in tandem so that when I pull a tile into my project it will have those classifications per-categorized, or do I have to do that with each tile?

The VGIN data would be SUPER useful, if only I could wrangle it! I'd be happy to have this be a Python learning opportunity, but don't want to overcomplicate if I don't have to!

Comment: [Build virtual raster](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#build-virtual-raster) of tiles, then do the classification once.

Comment: @user2856 I just tried, but ended up with a large black square rather than a nice mosaic of my tiles...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build a .vrt virtual raster with the necessary tiles, and then manually entered the classification from provided metadata! The first time I had tried, I ran into issues, but I hit the "ignore projection differences" button and that worked... Probably not the best solution, but I have land use data that overlays with my other data points now so i'm not complaining